# How do I fix "invalid type argument of 'unary'?

Tags: c++

I've been running into this compiler error:

> invalid type argument of 'unary'

I did some research on what "unary" was and got operators such as `+,-.&`, so my guess is that I did a wrong operator somewhere. I'm only including the part of the code that has the error as the entire code is about 2000 lines long. Also there are other error's within the code, but they are the same so I assume if I can get an understanding of what is wrong with this one I should be able to figure out those.

```
static int cmp_bk( const void *ap, const void *bp)
{
    int a; 
    int b;
    dynamic_cast<const struct bk>(*a)=ap;
    dynamic_cast<const struct bk>(*b)=bp;

    if (a->hash < b->hash) return -1;
    if (a->hash > b->hash) return 1;
    return (int)a->bk - (int)b->bk;
}
```

The exact error I get is:

> invalid type argument of 'unary *'

and it's set to both the lines

```
dynamic_cast<const struct bk>(*a)=ap;
dynamic_cast<const struct bk>(*b)=bp;
```

Comment: this is my class bk. it is within a static union.
    static union {
static union {
 #define TTABLE (core.tt) 
        struct tt {                     /* Transposition table entry */
                ...omitted... not enough character room
 #define BOOK (core.bk)       
        struct bk {                     /* Opening book entry */
                unsigned long hash;     /* - Identifies position */
                short move;             /* - Move for this position */
                unsigned short count;   /* - Frequency */
        } bk[CORE];
} core;

} core;

Answer (score 2):

There is no unary `*` operator that applies to `int`, so `*a` doesn't make sense.

I believe what you may be after is a pointer to a `bk`, though:

```
bk * pa;
bk * pb;
pa = dynamic_cast<bk*>(ap);
pb = dynamic_cast<bk*>(bp);
```

This is just a wild guess, as I don't know how your `bk` class is defined. It's not clear that you really want a dynamic cast. It might be that a reinterpret-cast is what you're actually after.

I can't make sense of what you're trying to return, though, so if you explain that, I might be able to say more.

Comment: @K-ballo: Not entirely sure. I think so...? More importantly, I'm not sure if the OP really means to do a dynamic cast here. Perhaps `reinterpret_cast` is what's actually needed.

Comment: @K-ballo: You're right, the dynamic cast will never succeed, because `bk` is never a base class of `int`. So that is almost definitely wrong, and it should probably be a reinterpret-cast.

Comment: okay, so I changed it to reinterpret_class, and followed your code, but now it's saying bk is undeclared. My bk struct is within a static union. I tried to edit my original post, but it did not good and so i added a comment but it's ugly and pretty much unreadable.

Comment: well shorthand, this is the part of the program, that's supposed to read from another file called book(bk) and then transfer it to a transposition table(tt, where I also receive the same error), and then from there it allows the computer to make the best move.

Answer (score 1):

`a` and `b` are `int`s, what is `*a` supposed to do on an integer? Also your cast looks odd, I assume you want to `reinterpret_cast` to pointers to `bk`.